# How to change the title text on the invoice email?

Tags: magento-1.8, email, sales, email-templates

How can I change the title text on the invoice email?

I always get this in my email when I make an order,

```
XX Store: Invoice # for Order # 100000037
```

I want to **remove** the **#** after the word of 'Invoice',

```
XX Store: Invoice for Order # 100000037
```

Is it possible? where can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the template `/app/locale/{lang_ISO}/template/email/sales/invoice_new.html` and modify the first line:

```
<!--@subject  {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Invoice # {{var invoice.increment_id}} for Order # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->.
```

Make it:

```
<!--@subject  {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Invoice for Order # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->
```

Do the same for `invoice_new_guest.phtml`